# Fixed height with a fluid max-height text area - overflow auto

Tags: jquery, css, height, flexbox

http://codepen.io/africanmatt/pen/IcGpa

```
.text {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
}

.text-active {
  max-height: 50%;
}
```

I need to resize the .text component's max-height proportionally with the height of the right hand column on window resize so that the left and right hand column stay exactly even in height. I could be missing something simple here. I'm guessing JS could solve the problem by re-instating the max-height based on the window width and height, but surely there is an easier css solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
window.onresize = function(){
    $('.text').css('max-height', 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't just want to set the max-height to 100px though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you'll need JS to dynamically change the height of the text field. How you set the height will depend on how the field is lined up with what's next to it on the right side.

Right now the boxes above and below the text field are variable which moves it up and down and makes it tough to align with the right side. Is that how the left side will be in the end? You could set the text field in a more static position and then experiment with the max-height value in JS.